# Get Caller IP address using WCF 4.5 in and it should work in load balancing

Tags: c#, wcf

I searched in google and there are lots of solution but I do not get actual caller IP address. The sample code as follows:

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties properties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as 
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
string address = string.Empty;
//http://www.simosh.com/article/ddbggghj-get-client-ip-address-using-wcf-4-5- 
//remoteendpointmessageproperty-in-load-balanc.html
if (properties.Keys.Contains(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name))
{
  HttpRequestMessageProperty endpointLoadBalancer = 
  properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
  if (endpointLoadBalancer != null && endpointLoadBalancer.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"] != null)
    address = endpointLoadBalancer.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
 }
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
 {
   address = endpoint.Address;
 }
```

When I call service from the client application, I do not get client ip address, It always returns  **::1** not client IP address.
Any kind of hints or sample code is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'RemoteEndpointMessageProperty' property to get the client address information.
[image]
[image]

Service Code:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string UserIp(string name)
        {
            //Provides the context in which methods execute
            OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
            //Gets the properties of the incoming message
            MessageProperties properties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
            //Gets the remote endpoint IP and port where the message is sent
            RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello {0},You are  from {1}:{2}", name, endpoint.Address, endpoint.Port));
            return string.Format("Hello {0},You are  from {1}:{2}", name, endpoint.Address, endpoint.Port);


        }
    }
```

Client Code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceReference1.Service1Client wcfServiceProxyHttp = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client("BasicHttpBinding_IService1"))
            {
                string strUserName = "User1 ";
                string strMessage = "";
                
                strMessage = wcfServiceProxyHttp.UserIp(strUserName);
                Console.WriteLine(strMessage);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

OutPut:
[image]

::1in ipv6 equal to 127.0.0.1 in ipv4.

Best Regards

Qi You